# "Derived" binding in Unity (and UI Toolkit)

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity UI Toolkit has a nifty [data binding](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Binding.html) feature, but I'm a bit unclear how to use it in this particular scenario.

I have a GameObject in my game representing a character with a `health` field, which is a float in the range [0, 1], representing a percentage range from 0% to 100%. I want to display this in the UI as a percentage.

If I just use `binding-path` naively, it binds it as an unformatted float, which isn't what I want. Instead, whenever the float value changes, conceptually I want a new "derived" binding with my custom formatting logic, and then bind *that* to the UI. I'm looking for the best option for this in Unity.

JavaFX has something similar in [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) where you can generate bindings by performing calculations on other bindings.

---

What I have so far is this:

```cs
var label = row.Q<Label>(className: "pawn-health");
label.RegisterCallback<SerializedPropertyChangeEvent>(evt => {
    label.text = evt.changedProperty.floatValue.ToString("0.0%");
});
label.TrackPropertyValue(obj.FindProperty(nameof(Pawn.health)));
```

This actually does work, but it seems a bit heavy. I don't like that I have to use `TrackPropertyValue` instead of setting a `binding-path`.

Looking for suggestions for ways this can be improved or written in a more idiomatic way, or is the expectation that I have to write out code any time I want to format the bound value?

Comment: BTW I ended up not using bindings at all. UI Toolkit is intended for usage both in the game and in the Unity Editor, and...bindings only work in the latter. Still hoping for in-game data binding someday.